# Spring Security OAuth 2 client customize User Info Endpoint Requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, etsy

I am trying to implement a server client to authenticate to the Etsy API OAuth2 to get and manage store details.

Authentication works, but I am having issues with the user info endpoint call.

In the Etsy API the only 'appropriate' end point is getUser.

Two issues:

1. The getUser expects the Etsy UserId `/v3/application/users/{user_id}`, all the examples I have seen have a static uri.  Is it possible to dynamically provide this?
2. The Esty getUser expects a `GET` request and as far as I can tell the default user info call is a `POST`.  Can be configured?

Questions:

**Does this require a custom ClientRegistration class to adapt the user info endpoint request to work with the Etsy API endpoint?**

**If so, is there an example starting point for implementing this functionality?**

Details:

API documentation, Authentication:
https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference#section/Authentication

Note:  The {user_id} is prefixed to the access_token in the authentication response.  The response in theory should be parsed and the {user_id} used in the uri for user info request.

API documentation, getUser:
https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference#operation/getUser

Properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.etsy.client-id=REDACTED
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.etsy.client-secret=REDACTED
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.etsy.client-authentication-method=none
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.etsy.provider=etsy
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.etsy.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.etsy.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.etsy.scope=transactions_r

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.etsy.user-info-authentication-method=form
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.etsy.user-name-attribute=user_id
# Hard coded the user id, XXXXXXX, to prove the end point is reached, but the POST request fails (Etsy endpoint expects a GET)
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.etsy.user-info-uri=https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/users/XXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.etsy.token-uri=https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/public/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.etsy.authorization-uri=https://www.etsy.com/oauth/connect
```

Comment: Take a look at [Delegation-based strategy with OAuth2UserService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-oauth2userservice) in the reference docs, which provides an example of customizing the OAuth2UserService. I believe you can modify the request before invoking the delegate in that example.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRiesenberg I will check it out!  Hoping this is the tip / direction I was missing.